# Increment diamond coins by 1 every time the player gets 10 points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
switch(ScoreNumber.text)
        {
            case "9":
                DiamondPointTrack++;
                DiamondPoints.text = DiamondPointTrack.ToString();
                break;

            case "19":
                DiamondPointTrack++;
                DiamondPoints.text = DiamondPointTrack.ToString();
                break;
            case "29":
                DiamondPointTrack++;
                DiamondPoints.text = DiamondPointTrack.ToString();
                break;
            case "39":
                DiamondPointTrack++;
                DiamondPoints.text = DiamondPointTrack.ToString();
                break;
            case "49":
                DiamondPointTrack++;
                DiamondPoints.text = DiamondPointTrack.ToString();
                break;
            case "59":
                DiamondPointTrack++;
                DiamondPoints.text = DiamondPointTrack.ToString();
                break;
            case "69":
                DiamondPointTrack++;
                DiamondPoints.text = DiamondPointTrack.ToString();
                break;
            case "79":
                DiamondPointTrack++;
                DiamondPoints.text = DiamondPointTrack.ToString();
                break;
            case "89":
                DiamondPointTrack++;
                DiamondPoints.text = DiamondPointTrack.ToString();
                break;
            case "99":
                DiamondPointTrack++;
                DiamondPoints.text = DiamondPointTrack.ToString();
                break;
            case "109":
                DiamondPointTrack++;
                DiamondPoints.text = DiamondPointTrack.ToString();
                break;
            case "118":
                DiamondPointTrack++;
                DiamondPoints.text = DiamondPointTrack.ToString();
                break;
            case "127":
                DiamondPointTrack++;
                DiamondPoints.text = DiamondPointTrack.ToString();
                break;


        }
```

Right now I have this to increment my diamond points each time the player gets 10 points(says 9 because it starts at 0) Is there a way to make it so that each time the player gets 10 points I can increment the diamond coins by 1? By the way the score is in string since it won't take ints.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your exact situation but I imagine this could be achieved with much cleaner code. That long switch statement is not robust and also very inefficient.

I think something like this will work better. Just call the function whenever you would normally collect the coin. Of course, you can change this, it's just the basic idea.

```
private int score = 0;

private int diamonds = 0;
private int diamondIncrementTracker = 0;

public void CollectCoin()
{
    score++;
    ScoreNumber.text = score.ToString();

    diamondIncrementTracker++;

    if(diamondIncrementTracker == 10)
    {
        diamonds++;
        diamondIncrementTracker = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you're not updating your UI every Update frame. In which case you'd find it helpful to do something like this:

```
private int _Diamonds = 0;
private int _Score = 0;
public int Score
{
    get => _Score;

    set
    {
        var v = value;
        if ( v != _Score )
        {
            // If the new value is different to the current score, we update the Score Text.
            _Score = v;
            ScoreNumber.text = _Score;

            // Now that we know the score has changed, let's see if the number of diamonds needs to be updated.
            v = _Score % 10;
            if ( v != _Diamonds )
            {
                _Diamonds = v;
                DiamondPoints.text = _Diamonds;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What this will allow you to do is update your Score, for example `Score++` and your UI text elements will be only updated when the score values actually change. And by using the "modulo" operator, you're just asking how many times the score can be divided by 10. And that seems to be the scoring logic you want.